# Multiple Forms, Wrong Value Submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I have PHP code creating multiple forms on a single page and the submission of any of these forms should trigger an API call based on which form was submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['pickApples'])) {
  echo '<h1>Picking Apple ' . $_POST['appleId'] . '</h1>';

  // Function that calls API
  pickApple($_POST['appleId']);
}

// $listOfApples is a list of 10 apples each with a unique ID

foreach ($listOfApples as $apple) {
  echo '<form method="post" action="mypage.php">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="appleId" value="' . $apple->{"id"} . '">';
  echo '<button type="submit" class="my-button-class" value="click" name="pickApples">Pick Me</button>';
  echo '</form>';
}
```

No matter which of the form buttons I click, the value in `$_POST['appleId']` is the ID of the first apple in the list.  I don't have much experience with PHP or HTML forms, is my approach completely off?

Comment: Do you submit on click of the button or do you have some JavaScript setting up ajax calls?

Comment: Also why have more than one form? Only the clicked submit button will send its value on submit

Comment: @mplungjan
Right now I submit on click of the button.  I'm open to a solution that doesn't involve multiple forms but I'm not sure how else to approach the problem.

Comment: You for sure have a missing equals: `echo '<input type="hidden" name="appleId" value="' . $apple->{"id"} . '">';`

Comment: You want to trigger an API call on the client? How, please elaborate

Comment: Use _one_ form, and put the apple-id you need to submit into the `value` attribute of the `button` element …?

Comment: @mplungjan Good catch on the missing equals.  I retyped my code into Stack Overflow to simplify the question and hide some of the other things I'm doing in the foreach loop.  I have made the correction.

Comment: @mplungjan `pickApple($appleId)` uses cURL to call the API.

Comment: I've just tested your code, it works as should. Can you provide `var_dump($listOfApples)`? Or provide a code where it is filled. I afraid you're reusing the same object when filling the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing  some small mistakes as

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appleId" value"' . $apple->{"id"} . '">';
```

You should  fix it,instead of foreach yor can use for loop to display  forms,
as I haven't $listofapples,I used 10,you can query for row numbers than place row numbers value as $listofapples,then echo your unique id to input value,
Finally  it's working as you wished
Check it & let me know if it's the perfect fit for you

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pickApples'])) {
  echo '<h1>Picking Apple ' . $_POST['appleId'] . '</h1>';

  // Function that calls API
  pickApple($_POST['appleId']);
}

$listOfApples = 10;
// $listOfApples is a list of 10 apples each with a unique ID
$sn=0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $listOfApples; $i++) {
  echo '<form method="post" action="hy.php">';
  
  
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="appleId" value=" ' .++$sn. '"/>';
  
 

  echo '<button type="submit" class="my-button-class" value="click" name="pickApples">Pick Me</button>';
  
  echo '</form>';
}
?>
```